Visual Studio doesn't allow to unselect radio button in Text Editor section
I was needed to change document formatting for JSON -> Tab: Indent size = 2 and Insert spaces, but by mistake I've made this changes for all langueages ( Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages->Tabs).

When I was trying to revert back default setting for All Languages I wasn't able to unselect radio button, so I had to reset my visual studio setting to default state. My question is, is this a bug or Am I missing some settings?
Environment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.9.6;
Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

you could export the settings, then change the setting, and export again. Then (try to) find the differences.... (NOTE: There is no such thing as KeepTabs in the export)

It's either keep tabs or insert spaces. The default one is tabs, I think but the default value is not reflecting here. Once you select it, unlike checkbox, you can't remove selection from radio

so, it's not a bug, but a feature ....

Can be a feature, but looks weird for me. As a user I open tabs section and see nothing is selected in radiobatans, but once I select - I can't cancel my action

It could be that other language-specific settings are conflicting with the All Languages setting. You can check to see if any other languages have indentation settings that are inconsistent with the settings you are trying to change. If so, you may see the message "The tab settings for individual text formats conflict with each other,"
One more tip is that adaptive formatting may override your custom label settings. You can turn off Use adaptive formatting in Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced.

Hey, Cody! Thanks for you response. I'm seen the message "The tab settings for individual text formats conflict with each other" and adaptive formation is checked. I'm just thinking is it possible to unselect radio button Tab setting if I clicked by mistake and would like to undo.

This issue is a bit tricky, and I suggest you upload this issue on DC for help: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home
